# What is the real difference between INDEX.TOKENIZER vs INDEX.ANALYZER in Lucene 2.9?

Tags: lucene

With lucene 2.9.1, INDEX.TOKENIZED is deprecated.  The documentation says it is just renamed to ANALYZER, but I don't think the meaning has stayed the same.  I have an existing app based on 2.3 and I'm upgrading to 2.9, but the expected behavior seems to have changed.

Anyone know any more details about INDEX.TOKENIZER vs INDEX.ANALYZER?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you refer to the [`Field.Index`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html) fields [`ANALYZED`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html#ANALYZED) and [`TOKENIZED`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html#TOKENIZED)?

It is true that the `TOKENIZED` Field has been deprecated. This was the case already with the [2.4](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1366).

The `Field.Index.ANALYZED` is equal to the old `Field.Index.TOKENIZED`. Could you show how your results deviate from the behaviour you expect?

Comment: thanks for the answer, was so long ago now I don't have access to the code any more, sorry for such a long delay in responding